# How to create a tab set against the side of the browser window?

Tags: css, tabs, transform

I'm trying to create a sideways tab set against the side of the browser window - something like this:

[image]

The relevant css code so far:

```
left: -29px;
transform: rotate(-270deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-270deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(-270deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform: rotate(-270deg); /* Opera */
-moz-transform: rotate(-270deg); /* Firefox */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1); /* for earlier versions of IE */
```

This works perfectly for Firefox, Chrome, and IE9 - for previous versions of IE, though, the tab doesn't show up. The problem seems to be the `left: -29px;` code; if I set it to 0 it looks correct in IE8 and earlier, but not in IE9, Firefox, or Chrome.

What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an interim hack, you could add an IE version conditional stylesheet that overrides the `left` property to 0:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <style>

    #myElement {
        left: 0px;
    }

    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

The problem here is probably that the origin about which the rotation occurs is not the same. I'll see if I can find anything on specifying the origin for the transform.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... but I'd really like to find a less "hacky" way of doing this if possible...

Comment: @froadie I suspect you aren't entirely happy with this answer. Did you know you can edit your question, which bumps it to the front page? That way you get more people viewing it, and hopefully that will generate some answers. If you do decide to do this, you should unaccept this answer first.